# c++ check variable to address out of bounds

Tags: c++, c, memory, certificate

I use some function, and this function return variable  of LPWSTR type (wchar_t*)

at debugger i look at this variable and see error "0x2e (Address 0x2e out of bounds)" 
and when i do some operations with its variable, my program terminated.

I can't change called function, i haven't its src code.

my question is : Is c/c++ language have functions to check situation before call incorrect variable? i try try/catch block, but its not helped.

Excuse me for my english and thanks for any help

edited:

fragment of code with error

```
PCERT_EXTENSION pCe = CertFindExtension(szOID_CRL_DIST_POINTS, pCertInfo->cExtension, pCertInfo->rgExtension);
    if (pCe) {
        PCRL_DIST_POINTS_INFO pCrlDistPointsInfo = NULL;
        PCRL_DIST_POINT *pCrlDistPointsPtr = NULL;
        PCRL_DIST_POINT pCrlDistPoints = NULL;
        DWORD pdwCrlDistPoints = sizeof (CRL_DIST_POINTS_INFO);

        if (!CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
                szOID_CRL_DIST_POINTS,
                pCe->Value.pbData,
                pCe->Value.cbData,
                CRYPT_DECODE_ALLOC_FLAG,
                (PCRYPT_DECODE_PARA) NULL,
                &pCrlDistPointsInfo,
                &pdwCrlDistPoints)) {
            printf("\n\nCannot decode CRL URL.\n\n");
        }

        if (pCrlDistPointsInfo) {

            pCrlDistPointsPtr = (PCRL_DIST_POINT*) pCrlDistPointsInfo->rgDistPoint;

            if (pCrlDistPointsPtr && pCrlDistPointsInfo->cDistPoint > 0) {

                findCDP = true;
                fwprintf(pFile, L"^^"); 
                for (int i = 0; i < pCrlDistPointsInfo->cDistPoint; i++) {

                    pCrlDistPoints = &pCrlDistPointsInfo->rgDistPoint[i];

                    if (pCrlDistPoints) {

                        LPWSTR str = (LPWSTR) pCrlDistPoints->DistPointName._empty_union_.FullName.rgAltEntry->_empty_union_.pwszURL;


                        //printf("last error= 0x%08X", GetLastError());
                        fwprintf(pFile, str);//PROGRAM TERMINATED HERE!!!
                        fwprintf(pFile, L";");

                    }
                    printf("%d\n",i);
                }

            }

            free(pCrlDistPointsInfo);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does this mean in your question, what error: *at debugger i look at this variable and see error "0x2e"* ?

Comment: What does the documentation of this function say about the return value?

Comment: It is probably using the low addresses for error codes. Read the documentation.

Comment: Address 0x2e out of bounds, value not showed in tags, i fix it

Comment: The right way is to debug the cause why value in the respective function is modified wrongly to `error "0x2e (Address 0x2e out of bounds)"`. Which all ways this variable can be modified and who modified it instead checking for incorrect value before to function call.

Comment: Btw, do you understand the concepts of pointers and 0-terminated strings (wide char strings in this case) in C?

Comment: this function - function about get CDP from certificate structure. i have only one certificate, where i see its problem. at all other certificates all is ok/ i get from certificate structure PCRL_DIST_POINT, and in cycle  PCRL_DIST_POINT pCrlDistPoints pCrlDistPoints = &pCrlDistPointsInfo->rgDistPoint[i];
LPWSTR str = (LPWSTR) pCrlDistPoints->DistPointName._empty_union_.FullName.rgAltEntry->_empty_union_.pwszURL;

str variable is incorrect

Comment: i am a java developer) i understand c++ very bad and want to get round this situation and come back to java development)

Comment: Especially if you are unsure of your C(++), you should definitely add code to the question... Interesting bits are, how you read in the certificate in your program, and how you create the parameters for this "some function" you call and how you do the call. Perhaps the failing certificate is unsupported format or simply corrupted, and you fail to handle error when reading it?

Comment: I edit question and add code fragment

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't have. If you set a pointer, which points to an invalid memory location, every access to the object at that location is an undefined behavior. What will most likely happen is a crash or some kind of memory corruption.

Answer (score 3):

If a pointer has value `0x0000002e`, it can mean only two things:

- A bug in code which returns that. You're out of luck if you can't fix that...
- An undefined pointer value, and reason for error is returned some other way, such as by modified reference parameter. But returning undefined value instead of null pointer would still count as a bug in my book.

On the other hand 0x2e sounds like ASCII character, `'.'` to be exact, so are you sure you are looking at pointer value instead of the string pointed to?

Late edit: looking at the code, it seems unions are involved. A possible reason for crash then is, you are accessing wrong member of union. In C union, all members/fields are in same memory location, they overlap. In other words, union can hold only one value at a time, and you need to know which one somehow, such as from documentation of function which initializes the union value, or by some extra variable which tells the type (common pattern in C is to have struct which contains type field and union field).

Comment: see my comment under question  - there i write some text about function

Comment: @mgurov Your problem is probably long solved or worked around, but edited my answer anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Windows has functions to check whether an address is a correct address or not.  BUT... it's bad practice to rely on this, since there is no guarantee that if the pointer points to a correct address, that this is the address that you want.

The functions in windows are: IsBadReadPtr, IsBadWritePtr and IsBadCodePtr.  I strongly suggest to only use these functions in debugging code (asserts e.g.) and never rely on this in a release executable.

If your application is designed and working correctly, you should never rely on these Windows functions.